# Managing OpenStack through java

Tags: java, openstack, jclouds

I want to make changes in vm instances of openstack through my java code. 
How do I do that? I have installed jclouds package. Which classes can be used?
Are there any setter methods in java which can set the values for different vm statuses and handle vms through java.

Thanks
Avanti

Answer (score 0):

I would use [OpenStack4j](http://openstack4j.com)  It does everything your asking for and supports even creating snapshots of running instances.  It covers almost 100% of the native APIs but through java and is fluent based